# I keep having an empty page in front of my nomenclature

Tags: nomenclature, makeindex, nomencl, emptypage

I am doing a project work report and I keep getting the same problem. I have a nomenclature and just before it an empty page with the heading "Stichwortverzeichnis" which is german for index keeps appearing.

I want to get rid of the empty page as it interferes with my pagenumbering. I have the feeling that it might be caused by the \nomunit command.

Thank you for your help in advance!

[image: The empty page that keeps appearing]

[image: My nomenclature]

Here an excerpt of my latex code.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside,headsepline,captions=tableheading,toc=bibliography,openany,chapterprefix]{scrbook}


%% Nomenclature
\usepackage[noprefix,intoc,\iftoggle{lang_eng}{english}{german}]{nomencl}
\setlength{\nomlabelwidth}{.25\hsize}
\setlength{\nomitemsep}{-\parsep}
% Split nomenclature for symbols and abbreviations
\renewcommand{\nomgroup}[1]{%
\ifstrequal{#1}{C}{\vspace{3mm}\item[\textbf{\iftoggle{lang_eng}{Roman symbols}{Lateinische Symbole}}]}{
\ifstrequal{#1}{B}{\vspace{3mm}\item[\textbf{\iftoggle{lang_eng}{Greek symbols}{Griechische Symbole}}]}}{
\ifstrequal{#1}{A}{\vspace{3mm}\item[\textbf{\iftoggle{lang_eng}{Abbreviations and acronyms}{Abkürzungen und Akronyme}}]}{}}} 

%This is for my units on the right side of the page
\newcommand{\nomunit}[1]{%
    \renewcommand{\nomentryend}{\hspace*{\fill}#1}}
%----------------------------------------------


\makenomenclature %Generates a %tm.nlo file



\begin{document}

\setcounter{page}{1}
\pagestyle{headings} 
\pagenumbering{roman}
\renewcommand*{\chapterpagestyle}{\chapterpagestyleorig} % restore chapter pagestyle for the main content
\tableofcontents
\newpage

\listoffigures
\newpage


%% nomenclature
\input{content/nomenclature}
\cleardoublepage % fixes confused odd/even page order

\end{document}


%%-------------------------------------%%
This is the code of my nomenclature file
%%-------------------------------------%%

% Page style
\markboth{\nomname}{\nomname}% maybe with \MakeUppercase
\iftoggle{lang_eng}{}{\renewcommand{\nomname}{Nomenklatur}} % use german name

\mbox{}

\printnomenclature[4cm] % There is a bug TeXnicCenter version 2.0 Beta 1. As soon as this line is added to the document the structure pane indicates a missing paragraph. Nevertheless the nomenclature package works correctly. 

%% General variables
\nomenclature{$G$}{Gewichtskraft \nomunit{N}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have \newpage and then, when you call \mbox{}, it is positioned in the new page. When, afterwards, you call \printnomenclature, it goes to the top of another page. This is, the blank page you have contains the \mbox{}.

So, if you remove \mbox{}, the blank page should disappear.

Comment: Thank you, that worked!